# How to embed archetype project version in Maven archetype?

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

I'm creating a Maven archetype which generates a project skeleton that 
will include a dependency on the project from which the archetype 
originated.

For example, the origin project looks like:

```
origin/archetype/... archetype for generating project 
      /core/... core services 
      /extra/... extra services
```

and the archetype will generate a project with a POM that contains 
dependencies like so:

```
<dependencies> 
  <dependency> 
    <groupId>com.foo</groupId> 
    <artifactId>origin-core</artifactId> 
    <version>SOMEVERSION</code> 
  </dependency> 
</dependencies>
```

I want SOMEVERSION to be the version of the origin project at the time 
that the archetype is built and installed into the repository.

So if the origin project is at version 1.0-SNAPSHOT and is `mvn 
install`ed, then I want the archetype to generate a dependency on 
`origin-core 1.0-SNAPSHOT`. And when the origin project is released, and automatically 
bumped to version 1.0, I want the archetype to generate a dependency on 
`origin-core 1.0`.

Basically I'd like to use `${archetypeVersion}` as a Velocity variable in the archetype 
POM, but that doesn't seem possible.

Is there any other way of accomplishing what I'm trying to do here?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I asked the above question on the Maven mailing list a few days ago and got tumbleweeds. Fortunately, I eventually figured it out on my own. Here's at least one sane way to accomplish this:

Use Maven filtering on your `src/main/resources/archetype-resources/pom.xml` file to substitute in the current project version when building the archetype.

Here's how that's done:

Modify your `archetype/pom.xml` file to enable filtering on the `archetype-resources/pom.xml` file and not on anything else (because your archetype files will naturally have `${variable}`s all over the place and you don't want those to be substituted at build time, you want them to be substituted when the archetype is created).

```
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
    <includes>
      <include>archetype-resources/pom.xml</include>
    </includes>
  </resource>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>false</filtering>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>archetype-resources/pom.xml</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

Enable an escape character for use when filtering, so that you can escape all the variables in your archetype pom that need to remain as-is so that they can be substituted at archetype generation time:

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <configuration>
        <escapeString>\</escapeString>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

(Note the `<resources>` and `<pluginManagement>` elements shown above should be placed inside the `<build>` element of your POM.)

Use `${project.version}` in your archetype pom, where you want the version of your archetype project to be inserted, and escape all of the other variables that should remain unsubstituted until archetype generation time:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project ...>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>\${groupId}</groupId>
  <artifactId>\${artifactId}</artifactId>
  <version>\${version}</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
      <artifactId>origin-core</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: can't believe how easy this was. thanks for this! The issue, when you think about it, is that an archetype is also a maven project. So... using Maven to  build a project which then generates a Maven project. I found it very difficult to explain this to my colleagues, once I figured it out.

Comment: Great solution. However, this means that you have to escape all the original velocity style variables. I.e.: for velocity => `\${groupId}`; for maven filtering => `${project.version}`. If you prefer the opposite, it's also possible. E.g.: for velocity => `${groupId}`; for maven filtering => `@project.version@`. 

For this, you can use in the pom.xml > plugins > plugin > maven-resources-plugin > configuration: delimiters. E.g. have only ``<delimiters>
      <delimiter>@*@</delimiter>
     </delimiters>``

Answer (score 16):

An alternative solution to the accepted answer is to filter a default property in the [archetype's descriptor/metadata](https://maven.apache.org/archetype/archetype-models/archetype-descriptor/archetype-descriptor.html) file

This is done like so:

The maven filtering only filters this file:

```
<resources>
<resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
    <includes>
        <include>META-INF/maven/archetype-metadata.xml</include>
    </includes>
</resource>
<resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>false</filtering>
    <excludes>
        <exclude>META-INF/maven/archetype-metadata.xml</exclude>
    </excludes>
</resource>
</resources>
```

The archetype meta data file:

```
<archetype-descriptor ...>
    <requiredProperties>
        <requiredProperty key="projectVersion">
            <defaultValue>${project.version}</defaultValue>
         </requiredProperty>
    </requiredProperties>

    ...
</archetype-descriptor>
```

and the archetype's POM would be similar to before except that it would use the `projectVersion` required property value as the project version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project ...>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>${groupId}</groupId>
  <artifactId>${artifactId}</artifactId>
  <version>${version}</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
      <artifactId>origin-core</artifactId>
      <version>${projectVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

This approach has the advantage that it avoids having to escape all the property values in the archetype's POM and the resource plugin configuration that goes with it. Personally, I find all of that quite ugly and error prone.

It does mean that the user is asked to confirm or alter the project version when generating the archetype. Depending on the scenario, I guess this could be considered a good or a bad thing.

Comment: This solution is definitely better than the accepted one. Thanks you very much for this. It saves a lot of my time

Answer (score 1):

I tried something rather stupid and it seems to have worked.  I added the following to my META-INF/maven/archetype-metadata.xml file:

```
<requiredProperties>
    <requiredProperty key="archetypeVersion"> </requiredProperty>
</requiredProperties>
```

You would think it would know about it by default but it doesn't so this seems to remind it to use it.  Perhaps it is due to a bug in maven.

Comment: It doesn't work if you use interactive mode and you must filter archetype test resources. Optionally you can rely on @PhilMander answer to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

[@samskivert's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7223084/4173303) solution is great, but I searched an alternative to the ugly escaping `\$`.
So I configured a different [delimiter](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html#delimiters) for the *maven-resources-plugin*, hoping its easier to maintain.

My delimiter is `@archetypeProperty{*}` and my *archetype-resources/pom.xml* becomes:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project ...>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>${groupId}</groupId>
  <artifactId>${artifactId}</artifactId>
  <version>@archetypeProperty{revision}</version>


  [...]

</project>
```

I configured this delimiter in my *archetype/pom.xml*'s *pluginManagement* section and [disabled default delimiters](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html#usedefaultdelimiters):

```xml
  <properties>
    <revision>1.0</revision>
    [...]
  </properties>

  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
          <include>archetype-resources/pom.xml</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>archetype-resources/pom.xml</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>

    [...]

    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>
            <delimiters>
              <delimiter>@archetypeProperty{*}</delimiter>
            </delimiters>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        [...]
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
```